# Custom compound field update hook

Tags: 7, entities

I have a custom compound field working beautifully. Below is what I have defined in the hook_field_schema function:

```
function MODULE_field_schema(&$columns, &$indexes, &$keys) {
  $columns = array(
    'meat' => array(
      'type'        => 'int',
      'description' => 'Meat'
    ),
    'potatoes' => array(
      'type'        => 'int',
      'description' => 'Potatoes',
    ),
  );
}
```

Now I need to modify the schema like so:

```
function MODULE_field_schema(&$columns, &$indexes, &$keys) {
  $columns = array(
    'meat' => array(
      'type'        => 'int',
      'description' => 'Meat'
    ),
    'potatoes' => array(
      'type'        => 'int',
      'description' => 'Potatoes',
    ),
    'carrots' => array(
      'type'        => 'int',
      'description' => 'Carrots'
    ),
  );
}
```

The problem is that I am using this field on a few content types and I need a way to update those associated tables. Basically I need to know what hook I need to create to make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completed this in hook_update_n:

```
function MODULE_update_7201(&$sandbox) {

  // get all field names
  $field_names = array();
  $fields = field_info_instances('node');
  foreach ($fields as $node) {
    foreach ($node as $node_field => $field) {
      $field_names[$node_field] = TRUE;
    }
  }

  // load schema to update
  $columns = array();
  MODULE_field_schema($columns);

  // load all fields and check for type
  foreach ($field_names as $field_name => $junk) {

    // load field info
    $field = field_info_field($field_name);
    if ($field['type'] == FIELD_NAME) {

      // loop schema and check fields for existance
      foreach ($columns as $db_field_name => $db_field_schema) {
        if (!db_field_exists('field_data_' . $field_name, $field_name . '_' . $db_field_name)) {
          db_add_field('field_data_' . $field_name, $field_name . '_' . $db_field_name, $db_field_schema);
        }
        if (!db_field_exists('field_revision_' . $field_name, $field_name . '_' . $db_field_name)) {
          db_add_field('field_revision_' . $field_name, $field_name . '_' . $db_field_name, $db_field_schema);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```